# why @WebMvcTest Http Post Method is ResponseEntity<?> return `null`

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

- i'm coding on @WebMvcTest Spring boot test code
- HTTP Post Method testing
- but Post method test code returning `null`
- but Controller layer is Post Mapping method is having return value (e.g ResponseEntity

**controller layer**

```java
@PostMapping("/api/todos")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseTodoDto> createTodo(@RequestBody RequestTodoDto requestTodoDto){

    final ResponseTodoDto savedResponseTodoDto = todoService.createTodo(requestTodoDto);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(savedResponseTodoDto);
}
```

**test code**

```java
@Test
public void Todo_등록_API_Test() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    RequestTodoDto requestTodoDto = new RequestTodoDto();
    requestTodoDto.setContent("테스트 코드 작성하기");

    ResponseTodoDto responseTodoDto = new ResponseTodoDto();
    responseTodoDto.setId(1L);
    responseTodoDto.setContent("테스트 코드 작성하기");
    responseTodoDto.setCreateDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    responseTodoDto.setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime.now());


    // given
    given(todoService.createTodo(requestTodoDto)).willReturn(responseTodoDto);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/todos")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestTodoDto))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();


    /** empty  **/
    log.debug(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}
```

- i expect the output of log.debug is [{"id":1,"content":"테스트 코드 작성하기","createDate":"2019-07-02T23:43:09.636","updateDate":"2019-07-02T23:43:09.636"}]
  , but log debug is empty

---

+) **TodoService**
and TodoService @Service annotation is marking on the code

Like ~

```java
@Service
public class TodoService { ... }
```

```java
@Transactional
ResponseTodoDto createTodo(final RequestTodoDto dto){

    Todo todo = Todo.builder()
            .content(dto.getContent())
            .build();

    Todo savedTodo = todoRepository.save(todo);

    return modelMapperUtils.map(savedTodo, ResponseTodoDto.class);
}
```

Comment: What does the equals method of your request DTO look like? Likely it is isn't matching the mock

Comment: Are you creating a mock object for the todoService or are you autowiring it ? Try mocking it if not and try using when() method instead of given().

Comment: i try using when() method like 
```java
when(todoService.createTodo(requestTodoDto)).thenReturn(responseTodoDto);
```

but still body value is `empty`

Comment: Thank you very much ! i fixed my DTO code on ResponseTodoDto & RequestTodoDto. i add annotation, @EqualsAndHashCode. that test case response body not empty !!